# Understanding of the phrase "an **inspirational** speech"

Tags: word-meaning

an **inspirational** speech

Does the phrase mean "the speech gives people **new ideas**" or "the speech gives people **encouragement**  or makes people more active"?

Comment: It's a tricky question, but I guess it's mainly for "encouragement".

Comment: As the saying goes: *There is no such thing as a new idea*. I think inspirational speeches do exactly what their name suggests: they "inspire" the audience.

Answer (score 1):

[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/inspiration?showCookiePolicy=true) defines "inspiration" as:

> 1. stimulation or arousal of the mind, feelings, etc, to special or unusual activity or creativity

Therefore it may be assumed that an inspirational speech is intended to stimulate the audience to do something - which in turn can be considered encouragement.
The way an individual reacts or what kind of arousal is intended varies a lot, from a simple "all is well"-statement via a suggestion to think outside the box to a call to arms.